# Java Stream. Extracting distinct values of multiple maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to extract and count the number of different elements in the values of a map. The thing is that it's not just a map, but many of them and they're to be obtained from a list of maps.

Specifically, I have a `Tournament` class with a `List<Event> event` member. An `event` has a `Map<Localization, Set<Timeslot>> unavailableLocalizations` member. I would like to count the distincts for all those timeslots values.

So far I managed to count the distincts in just one map like this:

```
event.getUnavailableLocalizations().values().stream().distinct().count()
```

But what I can't figure out is how to do that for all the maps instead of for just one.

I guess I would need some way to take each event's map's values and put all that into the stream, then the rest would be just as I did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's do it step by step:

```
listOfEvents.stream() //stream the events
            .map(Event::getUnavailableLocalizations) //for each event, get the map
            .map(Map::values) //get the values
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) //flatMap to merge all the values into one stream
            .distinct() //remove duplicates
            .count();   //count
```

Comment: I’m not sure whether the coolness of method reference is high enough to justify using `.map(Event::getUnavailableLocalizations) .map(Map::values) .flatMap(Collection::stream)` instead of `.flatMap(event -> event.getUnavailableLocalizations().values().stream())`. The latter makes it easier to recognize the missing step from the OP’s approach to the final solution.